# Why does changing the Bootstrap Twitter modal fade.in class top percentage dynamically disables transition?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a Twitter Bootstrap modal that I'm trying to change the `top` percentage to because the content is long.  When I change the `top` percentage dynamically the transition to fade back up doesn't happen anymore.  Am I missing any code to get this working?  Thanks!

Code to dynamically change how far the modal is from the top of the page:

```
$('test_modal.fade.in').css('top', '36%');
```

Html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test_modal" data-keyboard="true" href="">Open Test Modal</a>
<div id="test_modal" class="modal fade hide in">
  <div id='modal-body'>test content</div>
</div>
```

Not doing this dynamically via a normal bootstrap twitter css override works.  The modal exists by transitioning back up:

```
#test_modal.fade.in {
  top:36%;
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing the number sign at the beginning of the selector: `$('#test_modal.fade.in').css('top', '36%');` Is that just a mistake in the question text or is that what's causing your problem?